# get object values as array in php

Tags: php, object

I have object  with setter and getter

```
  class obj{
     private $a;
     private $b;

  }
```

I would like to create an array that get only the value of the object , for example

```
array = ["1","2"]
```

tried get_object_vars but its an associative array

Comment: Use array_values() after that.

Comment: With private properties like that, `get_object_vars` should have returned an _empty_ array, not an associative array.

Comment: Why you cannot use associative array? It's mostly the same to use `array(0 => "1", 1 => "2");` or `array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);`

Answer (score 10):

To condense an associative array to an indexed array, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
array_values(get_object_vars($object));
```

However, given that you have `private` member variables, you might just want to use an array cast instead of [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
array_values((array)$object);
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/SYKaF)

Comment: thx but it is not take smth like :
  ["date":"responseObject":private]=>
  string(10) "03-08-2017"
i

Comment: That looks like a reflection result. See the results at 3v4l.org as added in my answer for evidence that `get_object_vars` alone does not provide `private` values.